# Swagger-ui not working with jackson-dataformat-xml

Tags: java, json, spring, swagger, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm building a rest API with Spring 4.3.18 and swagger documentation**(springfox 2.8.0)**. Everything works fine but if I add to my **pom.xml**  **jackson-dataformat-xml** dependency, **swagger-ui.html** won't show anymore. I think it's a problem about Spring http converters, cause looks like Spring takes the xml converter when I try to go to **swagger-ui.html** which needs the json converter. Actually I don't know how I can fix this, I really need the jackson dependency, so I can't remove it. How Can I tell Spring to use the json converter for that url ?I also noticed that when I try to reach **swagger-ui.html** my browser send in the http headers accept :  `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,` then Spring uses the xml converter to send the response, but swagger-ui needs json to work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update on this? I got the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

swagger ui doesn't work well with jackson-dataformat-xml. you can try the following.

1. You need to add header of content-type: application/json. if you need to call any api (e.g. /v2/api-docs), you need to add a http header to accept application/json through postman.
2. or ensure that the jackson message converter has higher priority than xml. for springboot, you can add.

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestHandler() {
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    List<MediaType> mediaTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
    mediaTypeList.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypeList);
    adapter.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
    return adapter;
}
```

3. easiest. sorry. remove the jackson-dataformat-xml dependency. try JAXB or something else.

you can read more here
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1835

Hope it helps.